# Creating charts using google chart api with partial data

Tags: charts

I want to create a line chart. Currently my graph look like this

[image]

The data is live so the chart should start at 9 AM and increase toward x-axis upto 4 PM

when a user generate chart at 12 PM. 
My expected result is (Note: Data is only available upto 12 PM.)

[image]

I could not find a way to generate above partial chart. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need hours till 4pm on x if it's only 12pm? Just get current time (full hour) and use it as top value for x-axis. That way you would have full chart for current hour. If user loads the page at noon, chart will show data till noon, otherwise till the end of the day.                                                   If you need to cut time value on x-axis at 4pm, you can add conditional that will either use current time, or 4pm, if it's after 4pm but less than 9am of the next day.

Comment: This is client requirement. I am already displaying chart the way you described here. Client want it in this way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I have understood this correctly.  The code in comments is the remainder of the data (from 12pm to 4pm).  Without this data the graph will show a partial graph as you require.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string');
        data.addColumn('number');
        data.addRows(8);    
        data.setValue(0, 0, '9AM');
        data.setValue(2, 0, '11AM');
        data.setValue(4, 0, '1PM');
        data.setValue(6, 0, '3PM');
        data.setValue(7, 0, '4PM');

        data.setValue(0, 1, 5480); // 9AM
        data.setValue(1, 1, 5475); // 10AM
        data.setValue(2, 1, 5490); // 11AM
        data.setValue(3, 1, 5490); // 12PM
        /*
        data.setValue(4, 1, 5500); // 1PM
        data.setValue(5, 1, 5490); // 2PM
        data.setValue(6, 1, 5530); // 3PM
        data.setValue(7, 1, 5560); // 4PM
        */

        var chart = 
           new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
           chart.draw(data, {width: 500, height: 240,
                          vAxis: {minValue: 5460, maxValue: 5560},
                          colors: ['#76A4FB'],
                          legend: 'none'
                         });
           }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How can i add 4 datarow for each hour? I need to update it after every 15 minutes.

Comment: To capture 9-4 every 15 minutes - you would need 30 rows of data (rather than 8). If you wanted hourly X axis labels you would need to set them at the following rows: 0,6,10,14,18,22,26,30

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that pointed me to the way: Explicitly setting `minValue` and `maxValue` values. In my example (which is pretty similar to the original question's), these were had to be set under `hAxis`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqChart jQuery Plugin. See these samples:

http://www.jqchart.com/samples/ChartAxes/DateTimeAxis

http://www.jqchart.com/samples/RealTime/LiveData